# How do you specify ApplicationDomain.currentDomain when loading via SWFLoader?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, module, applicationdomain

I'm using Flex Builder 3 to build what will be a fairly large project.  I'm suffering from modules stepping on each other and a conflict between application/module.  My structure looks something like the following:

Main Application
|--Application 2
    |--Application 3
    |--Application 3

(Application 2 is a child of the main application, while Applications 2 and 3 are siblings, children of Application 2)

In reality, it's more complicated than that, but this is where problems start.  In the end, I could have the tree four or possibly five levels deep...  If it can be made to work.  The main application file consists of little more than a canvas and a series of buttons.  The second application contains a vertical tab navigator with canvases as containers, a list and a tree view within two of the tabs.  Application 3 is very complicated, as is an event calendar in Application 4.  As long as no interaction takes place, everything loads and appears fine.  When looking at Modules 2 and 3, both have ComboBoxes.  The first to be accessed works correctly, but the second throws errors, what I take to be sandbox violations.  I converted Applications 2, 3 and 4 to Modules and used ModuleLoader to bring them in and to specify ApplicationDomain=currentDomain.  Now, the calendar functions in the last (now module) fails to display at all.  I can trace values and throw up Alert boxes so I know that it's at least loading, but nothing displays.  As a test, I stripped that module down to contain nothing at all but a Label that says "Test" and it displays fine, but as soon as I put it inside a Canvas component, nothing displays.  But if I convert that module back to an Application and load it using an SWFLoader, it displays fine, but I'm certain that as soon as I try to bring in another application parallel to it, I'm going to be back where I Started.  I can easily use so.data and LocalConnections to pass information back and forth, but how do I load an SWF in as an Application and specify an application domain?  It would be nice to have everything exist as currentDomain and play nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understand your blurb, but if your title is accurate, you may find [the sample on this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf619ab-7ff0.html) to be helpful.

Comment: This might do it, however when I try to use SecurityDomain, it gives me a sandbox violation.  If I remove that line, it seems to work, so far.  I'll need to build up a few more "Applications" and see how they behave.  I think the LoaderContext is what I needed.  
private function setMemberPanel():void {
 var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
// context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
 context.applicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain();
 memberContext.loaderContext = context;
 memberContext.source = "btl_memberTools.swf";
}